# How to string from map to Dropdownbutton items?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have map<dynamic, String> with units and names.

```
Map timeUnits = <dynamic, String>{
  TimeUnit.second: 'секунда',
  TimeUnit.minute: 'минута',
  TimeUnit.hour: 'час',
  TimeUnit.day: 'день',
  TimeUnit.week: 'неделя',
  TimeUnit.month: 'месяц',
  TimeUnit.calendarYear: 'год',
};
```

How to add String to Dropdownbutton? Dropdownbutton shows this problem "The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'."
Dropdownbutton code:

```
child: DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              underline: Container(),
              value: currentUnits[widget.convertorType],
              icon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 6),
                child: Image.asset("assets/icons/down-arrow2.png"),
              ),
              iconSize: 35,
              elevation: 20,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(114,137,218, 1)
              ),
              items: widget.items
                  .map(
                    (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: e == TimeUnit.calendarYear
                          ? Text("year")
                          : e.toString().length == 3
                              ? Text(e)
                              : Text(e.toString().split(".")[1]),
                      value: e,
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  updateCurrentUnit(widget.convertorType, newValue);
                  widget.calculate();
                });
              },
            ),
```